# Deserializing malformed json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to use JsonConvert to deserialize a string into an object, but I'm getting the exception:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path 'type.id', line 1, position 12.

This is happening because the input string is not a properly formed json string, I understand that. However, **the problem is that the string will never be a properly formatted json string and I cannot change that**, but nonetheless, I still need to deserialize it to an object.

The string:

```
"{type: {id: schoolType1516,req: true,edit: yes},name: {id: schoolName1516,req: true,edit: yes}}"
```

How can I convert this string to properly formatted json string so it can be deserialized to an object using JsonConvert?

Comment: I would recommend using quotes (`"`).

Comment: Is your question _"How to programatically fix this invalid JSON"_, or _"How can I parse and access the `type.id` element"_?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the string can never be properly formatted?  The best answer here is to go back to the source of the string and fix the output.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/

Comment: A bit dirty, but if your string is always in the same structure (presumably from a source you have no control over?) with reliable variables, you could use the .Replace(" ", "") function to remove spaces and add single quotes after {, before } and either side of :. Then parse it. If a school name comes through as "St Michael's" or something it won't work.

Comment: If the field names are known in advance then writing a pre-processor should be a viable option. I could attempt something if it would help (given the field name restruction).

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks Peter, that would def help.

Comment: If the `Regex` parsing isn't working, you could try catching the `JsonReaderException` and inserting the missing quotes at the specified locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `Regex.Replace`, like this:

```
// Exchange all words with words surrounded by `"`
// ((\\w+\\s+)*\\w+) becomes ((\w+\s+)*\w+), ie all words with possible spaces
var match = "((\\w+\\s+)*\\w+)";
// \"$1\" becomes "$1" which is the sequence for replace the first group (ie the one
// we caught above) with the same group but with extra "
var replacement = "\"$1\"";
var correctJSON = Regex.Replace(faultyJSON, match, replacement);
// Parse it.
var obj = ...
```

If feels good to use regex though, https://xkcd.com/208/ :)

Comment: what about `{type: two words}`? wouldn't that end up as `"type":"two" "words"`?

Comment: How could the regex be changed to support cases where there maybe commas (or colons, semi-colons, hyphens) in the value, or values might already be surrounded by quotes? e.g., {type: "two, words"} -> {"type": "two words"}

Answer (score 0):

If you can't go back to your datasource and fix it there, you can try to fix your JSON string.

If it stays this simple, like in your sample you can select every word and wrap it in quotation marks:

```
//we only need every match once
var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"\w+")
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select (m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                   .Distinct();

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    source = source.Replace(match, String.Format("\"{0}\"", match));
}

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(source);
```

Example: http://share.linqpad.net/sartkg.linq

Edit: fixed single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Hms, dangerous, ex { id : { id2 : PIZZA } }. All complete names must be partially unique =(

Comment: See my exaple, { id2 : { id : PIZZA } } => { ""id"2" : { "id" : "PIZZA" } }. Since first "id2" is replaced, and then "id".

Comment: Agreed, thankfully this isn't the case in the OPs question.